# How to multiply DOMMatrix and DOMVector in JS

Tags: javascript

I see the DOMMatrix API has lots of methods to build matrices.  But I cannot see any method to multiply a vector with the matrix.  Surely it must be there somewhere!  Easy reputation points to anyone who can tell me where it is

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen `DOMMatrixReadOnly.transformPoint()` which does the job. Strange that MDN makes the link red and doesn't describe the method.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a page for it. It does have a description on the parent page: "Transforms the specified point using the matrix, returning a new DOMPoint object containing the transformed point. Neither the matrix nor the original point are altered." Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrixReadOnly

Comment: True, it does describe the method.  I was too critical.  I guess the documenter didn't make a separate page because the description is enough for most readers.  What I have learned is to look at the documentation of the base class(es) for a full list of methods in MDN.